# Tensorflow mIOU and pixel accuracy bug?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, deeplearning4j, deeplab

Let's say I started training a tensorflow model from scratch with 1000 training steps. I get the following result at the completion of training.
[image]
[image]

Now, lets say I want to train for 2000 training steps from the previously saved checkpoint. I get the mIOU and pixel_accuracy = 1.0.
[image]

I am using '''TensorFlow v1.13.1'''. How can I fix this bug or problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my data-set. I was assigning background_tag=1, class_one=2, class_two=3. After modifying ground truth images python PIL everything worked normally.